# Using waitForQualityGate in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

The following SonarQube (6.3) analysis stage in a declarative pipeline in Jenkins 2.50 is failing with this error in the console log: http://pastebin.com/t2ja23vC. More specifically:

> SonarQube installation defined in this job (SonarGate) does not match any configured installation. Number of installations that can be configured: 1.

**Update:** after changing "SonarQube" to "SonarGate" in the Jenkins settings (under SonarQube servers, so it'll match the Jenkinsfile), I get a different error: http://pastebin.com/HZZ6fY6V

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get SonarQube task id and/or server name. Please use the 'withSonarQubeEnv' wrapper to run your analysis.

---

The stage is a modification of the example from the SonarQube docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline

```
stage ("SonarQube analysis") {
     steps {
        script {
           STAGE_NAME = "SonarQube analysis"

           if (BRANCH_NAME == "develop") {
              echo "In 'develop' branch, don't analyze."
           }
           else { // this is a PR build, run sonar analysis
              withSonarQubeEnv("SonarGate") {
                 sh "../../../sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670/bin/sonar-scanner"   
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }

  stage ("SonarQube Gatekeeper") {
     steps {
        script {
           STAGE_NAME = "SonarQube Gatekeeper"

           if (BRANCH_NAME == "develop") {
              echo "In 'develop' branch, skip."
           }
           else { // this is a PR build, fail on threshold spill
              def qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()
              if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {
                 error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate coverage failure: ${qualitygate.status}"
              } 
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

I also created a webhook, `sonarqube-webhook`, with the URL `http://****/sonarqube-webhook/`. Should it be like that, or `http://****/sonarqube/sonarqube-webhook`? To access the server dashboard I use `http://****/sonarqube`.

In SonarQube's Quality Gates section I created a new quality gate:

[image]

I am not sure if the setting in SonarGate is correct. I do use jenkins-mocha to generate an lcov.info file that is used in Sonar to generate the coverage data.

Perhaps the quality gate setting is the wrong setting to do? The end result is to fail the job in Jenkins if coverage % is not met.

[image]

Finally, I am not sure if the following configurations in the Jenkins system configuration are at all required:

[image]

And

(It's 9000 not 900... cut text in the screen shot)
[image]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: There are no screen shots of code in the post. The post is super clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was discovered to be a bug in the SonarQube scanner for Jenkins, when using a Jenkins slave for jobs (if the job is run on the master, it'd work). You can read more here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-282

I have tested this using a test build of v2.61 of the scanner plug-in and found it working.
The solution is to upgrade to v2.61 when released.

This stage will then work:

```
stage ("SonarQube analysis") {
   steps {
      withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
         sh "../../../sonar-scanner-2.9.0.670/bin/sonar-scanner"   
      }

      def qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()
      if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {
         error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate coverage failure: ${qualitygate.status}"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The SonarQube Jenkins plugin scans the build output for two specific lines, which it uses to get the SonarQube report task properties and project URL. If your invocation of `sonar-scanner` does not output these lines, the `waitForQualityGate()` call won't have the task ID to look them up. So you will have to figure out the correct settings to make it more verbose.

See the `extractSonarProjectURLFromLogs` and `extractReportTask` methods in the [SonarUtils](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/utils/SonarUtils.java) class of the plugin to understand how they work:

- `ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse <project URL>` is used to add a link to the badge (in the build history)
- `Working dir: <dir with report-task.txt>` is used to pass the task ID to the `waitForQualityGate` step

Comment: Thanks, but all of this is not mentioned in the docs for this feature. In fact the doc is so light weight that it makes it seem very much plug&play. If it isn't as such then SonarQube really needs to make the integration smoother than it seems.

Comment: That's not mentioned because it is technical implementation details. We aim at making it "plug and play" and we failed, at least for Gradle projects. Still it should work for other cases. We are investigating a master/slave problem.

Comment: Thanks, I do use a slave in my Jenkins setup. The same slave (build machine) also hosts the SonarQube server.

Comment: If you need me to make any experiments on my end, please let me know.

Comment: The link to SonarUtils helped me to figure that the `report-task.txt` was only considered from the active (Jenkins) workspace instead of the current directory. I.e. running `cp /app/.scannerwork/report-task.txt .` before the waitForQualityGate() fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

If you're running SonarCube in a docker container check that the memory isn't exhausted. We were maxing out. Which seemed to be the issue.