# JenkinsFile for Sonar Quality Gates doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have read the documentation of Jenkins and Sonar to write and configure my pipeline and everything works except the Sonar Quality Gate which remains for the response from the Sonar without success. This is my code :

```
    pipeline {
    agent master
    tools {
        jdk 'JAVA'
        maven 'mvn_3_5_2'
    }
    stages {
        stage('test Java & Maven installation') {
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
                sh 'which java'
                sh 'mvn -version'
                sh 'which mvn'
            }
        }
        stage('Clean stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -f project/pom.xml clean'
            }
        }

        stage("build & SonarQube analysis") {
          node {
              withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar') {
                 sh 'mvn -f project/pom.xml org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar'
              }    
          }
        }

        stage("Quality Gate"){
          timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES') {
              def qg = waitForQualityGate()
              if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                  error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
              }
          }
        }        
        stage('Test stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -f project/pom.xml test'
            }
        }
        stage('Build stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -f project/pom.xml install'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deployment...'
               // sh 'mvn -f project/pom.xml appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.project=acn-shelf-check -Dapp.deploy.version=v1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the stage "Quality Gate" I never received the result. I have configured the webhook on the sonar with correct URL of Jenkins.
Do I miss any step?

Comment: Check your Jenkins log (the server log, not the job log) to see if the webhook call is being received. It's likely it's not & you need to doublecheck that config.

Comment: check this related issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909439/using-waitforqualitygate-in-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)